# MySQLi fetch as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

**ANSWER:** It turns out that I had to install `mysqlnd` through `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`.

I am using PHP and mysqli. How do I fetch data from my database as an array? I currently do this, but i want it as a array:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT username, display_name, registered_on, ip_address FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $display_name, $registered_on, $ip_address);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Thank you

Comment: [`$stmt->fetch_assoc();`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)?

Comment: @Sean I get the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048622/how-to-fetch-all-in-assoc-array-in-mysqli You need to do `->fetch_result()` first -> `$result = $stmt->fetch_result(); $data = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: @Sean I still get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_result()`. :/

Comment: Try [`->get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) -> `$result = $stmt->get_result(); $data = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`. :/

Comment: are you using the standard mysqli library/connection, ie. `$cxn = new mysqli(...);` or is it a custom mysqli library/connection?

Comment: I'm doing `$cxn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);`.

Comment: It turns out that I had to install `mysqlnd` through `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `username`, `display_name`, `registered_on`, `ip_address` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '{$user_id}'");
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```